# remove certain files in a list matching a pattern

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list with files (the path to them).

I wrote a function like this to remove certain files matching a pattern but it just removes 2 files at most and I don't understand why.

```
 remove_list = ('*.txt',) # Example for removing all .txt files in the list
 def removal(list):
     for f in list:
        if any(fnmatch(basename(f.lower()), pattern) for pattern in remove_list:
            list.remove(f)
     return list
```

//Edit; Ok naming my list "list" in the code was a bad idea. in my code here its called differently. Just wanted to give an abstract idea what I'm dealing with. Should have mentioned that

Comment: Bad idea to use `list` as a variable name/placeholder - shadows built in name `list`.

Comment: you should iterate remove_list

Comment: Don't modify the list while iterating over it. That will introduce errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying a list while you're iterating over it is a bad idea, as you can very easily get in edge cases when behaviour is not determined.

The best way to do what you want is to build a new list without the items you don't want:

```
remove_list = (r'*.txt',) # Example for removing all .txt files in the list
def removal(l, rm_list):
  for f in l:
    for pattern in rm_list:
      if not fnmatch(basename(f.lower()), pattern):
        yield f

print(list(removal(list_with_files, remove_list))
```

Here, I'm unrolling your `any` one-liner that might make your code look smart, but is hard to read, and might give you headaches in six months. It's better (because more readable) to do a simple `for` and an `if` instead!

The `yield` keyword will make the function return what's called [a generator](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html?highlight=generator%20expression#generator-expressions) in python, so that when you're iterating over the result of the function, it will return the value, to make it available to the calling context, and then get back to the function to return the next item.

This is why in the print statement, I use `list()` around the function call, whereas if you iterate over it, you don't need to put it in a list:

```
for elt in removal(list_with_files, remove_list):
  print(elt)
```

If you don't like using a generator (and the `yield` statement), then you have to build the list manually, before returning it:

```
remove_list = (r'*.txt',) # Example for removing all .txt files in the list
def removal(l, rm_list):
  ret_list = []
  for f in l:
    for pattern in rm_list:
      if not fnmatch(basename(f.lower()), pattern):
        ret_list.append(f)
  return ret_list
```

HTH

Comment: I think you want to replace your calls to `remove_list` with `removal`.

Comment: @zmo I can get the idea of writing my code easier even tho I don't feel it was that difficult. On the other side I'm not quite happy with the code you provided :D. Why does the function itself not `return` the "cleaned list" would it be okay to add that instead of the `yield`

Comment: well, not only it's more readable to break the oneliner, but a for-loop (or a list comprehension) is always more time optimised than a `any()` filter (same goes for all those functions, `filter`/`map`/…). So if you really like one liners, use list comprehensions ☺.

Comment: this time it returns the list with the files I don't want to have in my list tho but I think this is pretty close to what I tried to do in the first place!

Comment: sorry, I forgot to negate the if when I rewrote, it was just a typo☺

Comment: it's not exactly what you've done in your Q, because you were trying to remove the items you don't want on the list you're iterating on, whereas in my version, I'm building a new list with just the items you want.

Comment: (I find my first version very pretty, with a 45° indentation :P)

Comment: ok you're right again.. in the end the result from your approach is what I had in mind ;).  I can work with the second solution of yours. Thanks!

Comment: You should try learning and using generators, they're really powerful and elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *str.endswith* if you are removing based on extension, you just need to pass a *tuple* of extensions:

```
remove_tup = (".txt",".py") # Example for removing all .txt files in the list
 def removal(lst):
     return [f for f in lst if not f.endswith(remove_tup)]
```

Comment: thanks but removing based on the extension was just an example. Might wanna specify the ignore list further,

Comment: @randomStranger, so you are matching anywhere  or just multiple extensions because endswith can take as many extensions as you like

Comment: in the end it will be a list of different files and fileextensions

Comment: @randomStranger, are we talking full matches for the files or a pattern match

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is vague.
1.don't use `list` it is shadow the build-in `list`

2.don't modify the list when you iterate it, you can make a copy of it

My suggestion is:
You can iterate your original list and the remove_list as below:

test.py

```
list1=["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "other.csv"]
list2=["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]  # simulates your remove_list

listX = [x for x in list1 if x not in list2]  # creates a new list

print listX
```

$python test.py

```
['other.csv']
```

Comment: That's nice, but you're not answering to the OP. He wants to check whether the names in `list1` match a pattern from `list2`. Because a better way to write your answer would be `set(list1).intersection(list2)`.

Answer (score 0):

As was said in the comments, don't modify a list as you iterate over it. Can also use a list comprehension like so:

```
patterns = ('*.txt', '*.csv')
good = [f for f in all_files if not any(fnmatch(basename(f.lower()), pattern) for pattern in patterns)]
```